# How can I convert the caption file format (.xml to .vtt)?

Tags: video-editor, subtitles, closed-captioning, xml

I'm looking for your help and suggestion how to get started with CC conversion from `.xml` to `.vtt`.

We are having lots of flash files where we have `xml` to `vtt` during a project migration. I tried with many online tools most don't have solution for this.

Could you please help me how to start on this. Suggest me any tools/online converters which can do this job for me.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: I can highly recommend the Subtitle Converter from https://www.editingtools.io/subtitles/, which converts almost all subtitle formats.

Answer (score 0):

[Closed Caption Converter](https://app.closedcaptionconverter.com/) claims to be able to convert from TTML (XML) to VTT captions. I don't have a source file unfortunately, so I cannot confirm.

What tools have you tried thus far?

Comment: I have tried below online and offline tools. 
[Go transcript](https://gotranscript.com/subtitle-converter)
[Closed Caption Converter](https://app.closedcaptionconverter.com/)
[Suvtile Edit](https://www.videohelp.com/software/Subtitle-Edit)

Comment: --- here is the sample code format


<captions>
<caption time_in="0.64" time_out="4.74" action=""><![CDATA[Line 1]]></caption>
<caption time_in="4.75" time_out="8.05" action=""><![CDATA[line 2]]></caption>
<captions>

Comment: I hope you're familiar with Python then, because this seems to be the only solution: https://github.com/nrk-rip/nrk-rip/blob/master/ttml2srt.py

Comment: Thank you @John Pooley for your suggestions. Finally I'm able to achieved the targeted solution using Node JS